Rust iterator map callback issue "function is expected to take 1 argument, but it takes 3 arguments expected function that takes 1 argument"
This "do_work" function Need to insert 3 arguments, but only first argument is working. Please view image.
I also need to insert i2 and i3 variables.
Rust  map callback issue - "function is expected to take 1 argument, but it takes 3 arguments expected function that takes 1 argument".

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

@kmdreko Ah, right. Not sure how I missed that... I've done similar things myself, even.

Instead of passing do_stuff directly to map, try using a closure in between. Minimal example:
fn do_stuff(i: usize, i2: usize, i3: usize) -> usize {
    return i + i2 + i3;
}

fn main() {
    let a: usize = 2;
    let b: usize = 3;
    
    let results: Vec<usize> = (0..100).map(|i: usize| do_stuff(i, a, b)).collect();
}

The |i: usize| do_stuff(i, a, b) acts like an adapter or proxy, transforming the three-argument do_stuff into a single-argument function that std::iter::Iterator::map will accept.

Note the type annotation on the closure parameter is unnecessary. The compiler can infer it based on the type of the do_stuff parameter.
